# Какие ip checker'ы/blacklist'ы использует Google?

Tags: сеть, ip

Интересует проверка совпадения ip адреса с теми, что банятся гуглом
Есть ли какой-нибудь чекер/blacklist, который использует google?

Comment: https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search ?

Comment: @andreymal нет, интересует был ли замечен подозрительный трафик с хоста (будет ли гугл показывать капчу)